# Подгрузка контента без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html5-history-api

День добрый друзья. Есть одна проблема. Мне нужно сделать подгрузку контента без обновления страницы и c изменением адресной строки. Использовал history.js, но есть беда, у меня присутствуют еще и дополнительные ссылки в контенте, который подгружается. В конечном итоге они не работают. Мне посоветовали посмотреть в сторону pjax, но от него нету толку ибо мне нужно сымитировать обещение по средствам GET запросов, а там возможно только подгружать существующий файл. 
Вот мой код ( пример ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function send_url()
    {
        var arr =  window.location.href.split('?'); 
        $.ajax({
            url:        "api.php",
            type:       "GET",
            data:       arr[1],

            success: function(data) 
            {
                if(data != '')
                {
                    $(".content").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }



$(document).on('click', 'a', send_url);
</script>
<div class="menu">
<a href="/?test=1">test</a> | <a href="/?test=2">test2</a>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

и php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['test']))
{
    echo '<a href="/?ll=3">ff</a>';
}elseif(isset($_GET['ll']))
{
    echo 'error';   
}
?>
```

можете пожалуйста скинуть пример, мучаюсь уже 4й день, ничего немогу придумать, буду очень признателен

Comment: Ничего не понял, с чего бы вдруг ссылкам не работать?

Comment: Если использовать history в подгружаемом контенте - он неработает.

Comment: Понять бы ещё, зачем тут вообще history.js) Достаточно ведь повесить по обработчику на каждую ссылку, получать контент аяксом и вызывать history.pushState после его получения

Comment: я опубликовал полный код ( сейчас его накатал ). Вот если подгрузится <a href="/?ll=3">ff</a> и при нажатии на нее страница обновица!

Comment: Ну так надо после получения контента просто слетевший обработчик заново повесить (вы понимаете, как работает `$(selector).click`?)

Comment: Каким образом ?

Comment: Простейший способ — почитать документацию jQuery, обнаружить там `$(document).on('click', 'a', функция)` и использовать это

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Все равно перезагружается, дело не в этом

Comment: Значит или неправильно применили, или должны быть ошибки в консоли

Comment: Я обновил код. Да не в этом дело, я не в первый раз вижу, что люди .такой ошибкой сталкиваютсы. Целый пост был на хабре про это, там советовали Pjax. Но я так и не понял как его прикрутить

Comment: Так ошибок в консоли всё-таки нету?

Comment: Нет. Просто для этих целей нужен другой метод решения, до которого я немогу допехать

Comment: Нет-нет, я себе несколько сайтов делал именно таким способом и у меня всё работает (и pjax внутри то же самое делает)

Comment: А можете скинуть готовый пример? если не трудно! Буду крайне признателен, если он будет работать ;3

Comment: Имел неосторожность упустить из виду, что надобно действие по умолчанию для ссылки прервать: `function send_url(event) { ...; event.preventDefault(); return false;}` Тогда у меня всё работает

Comment: Не, чет все равно перезагружается при переходе с подгруженной ссылки. Мб есть где нибудь пример?